# Lyx: Works Cited + (separate) Annotated Bibliography

Tags: lyx

I'm using mostly default settings in Lyx. How can I create two distinctly titled sections at the end, one for "Works Cited" and the next for "Annotated Bibliography"?

Also, if I have normal "Bibliography" entries I cannot find a way to add my annotation text after each one. How should I do the annotations for my "Annotated Bibliography"?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you use a BibTeX bibliography? The annotations, are they just some text added at the end of the bibliography entry? Can works appear in both the 'Works cited' and the 'Annotated bibliography'?

Comment: I don't use BibTex, simply make a Lyx Bibliography & type my entries there. Each annotation is just some text added at the end of a biblio-entry. Yes, the same work can appear in both sections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Two reference sections

To add two bibliographies with different headings, you can do the following:

1. Add the first reference section as usual, by selecting *Bibliography* from the styles dropdown menu.
2. Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to end the current bibliography.
3. Add an ERT with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, and write

   ```
   \renewcommand\refname{Annotated stuff}
   ```

   (Changing 'Annotated stuff' to whatever you want as the heading, of course.)
4. Add a new reference section as in 1., for your annotated works.

## Annotations

Just write them at the end of bibitem. If you want them to start on a new line, I'd add an ERT and write `\par`, just before the annotation. Remember to add a space after the `\par`, either inside or outside the ERT.

You could instead hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but this just ends the line, rather than creating a new paragraph, which `\par` does.

## Duplicate entries

For entries that are found in both reference sections, you could just copy-paste the entire entry. An alternative is to define a `\newcommand` for each such duplicate entry, and use this macro in the reference sections. Should you want to change the text, you just change the definition of the macro. So:

Either in the LaTeX preamble, or in an ERT placed for example just before the first reference section, add something like

```
\newcommand\somereferenceiwanttousetwice{Author, A. \textit{Brillant stuff} (2015). The Pub.}
```

(You may prefer a shorter name for the command.) You need to use LaTeX commands to format the entry, such as `\textit{}` for italic text and `\textbf{}` for bold text. 
To use this in your reference list, add an ERT and write `\somereferenceiwanttousetwice`.

## Example LyX file

Copy the code below the screenshot into a text editor and save it as `example.lyx`, then you can open it in LyX.

[image]

```
#LyX 2.0 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 413
\begin_document
\begin_header
\textclass article
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman default
\font_sans default
\font_typewriter default
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100
\font_tt_scale 100

\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_amsmath 1
\use_esint 1
\use_mhchem 1
\use_mathdots 1
\cite_engine basic
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
The text.
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
nocite{*}
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
newcommand
\backslash
someref{Author, A.

\backslash
textit{Brillant stuff} (2015).
 The Pub.}
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Bibliography
\begin_inset CommandInset bibitem
LatexCommand bibitem
key "key-1"

\end_inset


\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
someref
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Bibliography
\begin_inset CommandInset bibitem
LatexCommand bibitem
key "key-3"

\end_inset

This only occurs once.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
renewcommand
\backslash
refname{Annotated stuff}
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Bibliography
\begin_inset CommandInset bibitem
LatexCommand bibitem
key "key-4"

\end_inset


\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
someref
\backslash
par
\end_layout

\end_inset

 Annotation.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Bibliography
\begin_inset CommandInset bibitem
LatexCommand bibitem
key "key-5"

\end_inset

This is just found here.

\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
par 
\end_layout

\end_inset

Annotation.
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: Works great (on Mac it was Cntrl-Enter). Thanks!